# How do I get the size of a merged Excel cell in perl?

Tags: excel, perl

I'm trying to implement code in Perl to parse a large Excel sheet as the below Excel example:

[image: My Excel example image]

For example, in the attached image you can see that 3 elements are assigned as named `"rsvd"` `"frame_kind"` and `"destination"`.

So I want to make a data structure with the size of a merged excel cell in Perl.

eg) what I want to get the information is that `rsvd` has merged  from 16 to 31 and the size of `rsvd` 16.

`frame_kind` has merged from 14 to 15 and the size of `frame_kind` 2.

`destination` has merged from 0 to 13 and the size of `destination` 14.

How can I get the location of a cell a certain merged number of cells away and size in Perl?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) module has a `get_cell` method which returns a [Cell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell) object.  The Cell object does not look like it directly tells how big it is, but you can use the `value` and `is_merged` methods to determine the size of the merged cells.

Start at the expected cell (`C6` in your example), then loop through the columns in Row 6, checking the value and whether the cell is merged.  The value will start at `rsvd`, and once the value is not `rsvd`, you know you found the end of the 1st merged cell.  Repeat this loop for the remaining columns in the row to get all merged cells.