# How to print a variable by push in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make an array variable which is pushed from an Excel file in Perl.

[image: Excel is]

```
my @registers=();
my $registers_num;

for (my $register_row = 0+3; $register_row < 5; $register_row++) {
    push( @registers,  $worksheet->get_cell( $register_row, 0));
}

print "register: ", $registers[0], "\n ";
$registers_num = @registers;
print "register_num:", $registers_num, "\n ";
```

When I execute Perl, I got the below.  I expected that the print `$registers[0]`= `ID`  and `$registers[1]`= `TOPINT`, but something went wrong.

```
register: Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH(0xd021bb8)
 register_num:2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel), as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912293/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-merged-excel-cell-in-perl), the `get_cell` method returns a `Cell` object, not the value in the cell.  To access the value of the cell, you should use the `value` method of the Cell object:

```
for (my $register_row = 0+3; $register_row < 5; $register_row++) {
    my $name = $worksheet->get_cell($register_row, 0);
    push( @registers,  $name->value() );
}
```

This stores only the cell values ("Register Name") in the `@registers` array.